# Feature Finding technique in Stitcher class of OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, opencv-stitching

I am working on image stitching project and want to know which Feature Finding and Feature Matching techniques does Stitcher class from OpenCV use as described at [this page](https://vovkos.github.io/doxyrest-showcase/opencv/sphinx_rtd_theme/class_cv_Stitcher.html#doxid-d7-d79-classcv-1-1-stitcher-1acb32106b3b3e7870d4b39082ab58a26e)  and at [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/stitching/doc/high_level.html#stitcher) .

Comment: Opencv is open source - did you try reading the source code? https://github.com/opencv

Comment: Specifically https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/stitching/src/matchers.cpp